# Access current array key while setting value

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array that is filled three times:

```
$forecast[] = [
    'forecast' => $calculatedForecast,
];
```

To produce the following array:

```
[
   [
      'forecast' => 10,
   ],
   [
      'forecast' => 20,
   ],
   [
      'forecast' => 30,
   ],
]
```

However I need to access the current array key to set in a internal value like this:

```
$forecast[] = [
    'period' => $array_key,
    'forecast' => $calculatedForecast,
];
```

To create the following array:

```
[
   [
      'period' => 0,
      'forecast' => 10,
   ],
   [
      'period' => 1,
      'forecast' => 20,
   ],
   [
      'period' => 2,
      'forecast' => 30,
   ],
]
```

While i could include a `$i = 0` and `'period' => $i++,`, I would prefer to do this in a more elegant way. Is this possible?

Comment: So it will always be the index at which those inner arrays are inserted?

Comment: @Yoshi Yes, it will always be the index of the outer array.

Comment: So `count($forecast)` then?

Comment: @Yoshi, That worked, cant believe it was this simple. Could you post it as an answer so I can make it as correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With code like this:

```
$forecast[] = [
    'forecast' => $calculatedForecast,
];
```

the right side will execute before the assignment. At that moment the *next index* is just the current number of elements in the array. So:

```
$forecast[] = [
    'period'   => count($forecast),
    'forecast' => $calculatedForecast,
];
```

will work.

---

Note though, that depending on the context in which this code executes keeping track of the next index like you described in your question (`$i++`) might be the better option.